# How to Multiply dynamic value in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to multiply dynamic value by 100 as payment gateway needs input in format of 2 decimal digits.

eg. when I try to multiply value by 2, instead of 499*2=998, i am getting 499499. How to resolve this issue

```
'amount': bag.bag_total*100 ,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if bag_total is a string you could parse it to a double/int to do the multiplication

```
//parses it to int
var a = int.parse(bag.bag_total);
//parses it to double
var b = double.parse(bag.bag_total);
```

Comment: This solution works. I made 2 edits: dynamic bag_total = 0 as int; &   bag_total = int.parse(result["bag_total"].toString());
This seems to be working